# Does R have an assert statement as in python?

Tags: r, assert, language-design, assertions

a statement that checks if something is true and if not prints a given error message and exits

Answer (score 139, accepted):

[`stopifnot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stopifnot.html)

You may also be interested in packages like [Runit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RUnit/index.html) and [testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html) for unit testing.

Comment: Is there a way to control the error message that is reported if stopifnot() stops?

Comment: @Nick, no. Use `stopifnot()` for validity testing, to test that code is doing what it's supposed to be doing, but `if (blahdiblah) stop("error message")` for input testing, to test that the input to the program is valid. Only the latter should ever happen during normal use.

Comment: See also Hadley's new `assertthat` package, which gives better answers than `stopifnot` does: https://github.com/hadley/assertthat

Comment: I wrote the assert package to provide more informative error messages and to keep dependencies light: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assert/index.html

Comment: Yes, there is a way to control error messages too... `stopifnot("1 + 1 is 2." = (1 + 1) != 2)`

Answer (score 12):

@Nick:

You can control your error message if you write a function with a descriptive name to test the condition that will throw an error in your program.  Here's an example:

```
Less_Than_8 = function(x) return(x < 8)

for (i in 1:10)
{
  print(i)
  stopifnot(Less_Than_8(i))
}
```

This will print the numbers 1 through 8, then print a message that says

```
Error: Less_Than_8(i) is not TRUE
```

It would be nice if the "i" in parentheses was replaced with the value that failed the test, but you get what you pay for.

If you need anything fancier than that, look into Runit and testthat as Harlan suggested.

Comment: You can just put the function definition inside `stopifnot()` too.

Comment: naught101, the point of having the test in a named function is to get the name of the test printed in the error message

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved with the `stop` command. This command will halt the execution of a function and print the error message. For example, we can test if the variable `something` is `FALSE`:

```
if(something == FALSE){
   stop("error message to print")   
}
```

Similarly, the `warning` command will print a warning (but continue executing the code).

```
if(something == FALSE){
   warning("error message to print")   
}
```

These are both provided by base R and require no packages to run or include in writing your own functions. I prefer this approach to write code with fewer dependancies and this syntax is widely used in package development. However, similar functionality is supported by the "assertthat" package with the `assert_that` function that has recently been released as part of Hadley's "tidyverse".

Answer (score 2):

### The testit-package

The `testit`-package provides the `assert`-function as a simple solution
(https://github.com/yihui/testit)

Examples:

```
assert('one equals one', 1==1)
assert('seq and : produce equal sequences', seq(1L, 10L) == 1L:10L)
assert('seq and : produce identical sequences', identical(seq(1L, 10L), 1L:10L))

# multiple tests
T=FALSE; F=TRUE
assert('T is bad for TRUE, and so is F for FALSE', T!=TRUE, F!=FALSE)

# a mixture of tests
assert("Let's pray all of them will pass", 1==1, 1!=2, letters[4]=='d', rev(rev(letters))==letters)
```

Source: https://github.com/yihui/testit/blob/master/R/testit.R

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [checkmate](https://mllg.github.io/checkmate)-package for that. From one of their examples:

```r
require(checkmate)

fact <- function(n, method = "stirling") {
  assertCount(n)
  assertChoice(method, c("stirling", "factorial"))

  if (method == "factorial")
    factorial(n)
  else
    sqrt(2 * pi * n) * (n / exp(1))^n
}

fact(2, method = 'blub')
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous responses to this question are quite dated, so I figured I'd add an answer that uses a modern package.  The assertr package in R is described well [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertr/vignettes/assertr.html) and documented [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertr/index.html). The assertr package makes uses of two primary functions to validate datasets: `verify` evaluates a boolean expression using the scope of a dataframe passed to it, and will throw, and log the error in the attributes of the dataset if the expression returns `FALSE`.  You can choose to continue processing the dataset if an error is discovered and treat the error much like a warning or you can instruct R to terminate processing.  This is useful for verifying dataframe structures and content.  For example, using the cars dataset, one might want to verify that it contains 32 rows of data.  One could do this with:

```
library(assertr)
cars %>% verify(nrow(.)==32, error_fun = error_append) %>% 
  attributes() %>% 
  pluck("assertr_errors")
```

The `assertr_errors` attribute will contain a list of validation errors that did not pass the verify check, so the above would produce the following:

```
[[1]]
verification [nrow(.) == 32] failed! (1 failure)

    verb redux_fn     predicate column index value
1 verify       NA nrow(.) == 32     NA     1    NA
```

You could also add other verification checks using the `assert` function as documented in the links below.  For example, continuing with the example above, we can verify that no observation in the variable speed exceeds the value of 23:

```
#Function that returns false if rule fails
is_greater_than_23<-function(x){
  x <=23
}

cars %>% assert(is_greater_than_23, speed, error_fun = error_append) %>% 
  attributes() %>% 
  pluck("assertr_errors")
```

Which returns:

```
[[1]]
Column 'speed' violates assertion 'is_greater_than_23' 5 times
    verb redux_fn          predicate column index value
1 assert       NA is_greater_than_23  speed    46    24
2 assert       NA is_greater_than_23  speed    47    24
3 assert       NA is_greater_than_23  speed    48    24
4 assert       NA is_greater_than_23  speed    49    24
5 assert       NA is_greater_than_23  speed    50    25
```

It's important to note that in the examples above I assigned `error_append` to the `error_fun` argument of the `verify` and `assert` function calls.  This allows R to continue processing the data when the check fails and logs the errors it detected to the `assertr_errors` attribute.  Once you've gathered your errors in this attribute, you can do all sorts of checking and additional verification steps as documented, again, in the links below.  If you want the program to stop processing when an error is encountered, you simply change `error_append` to `error_report`, which "prints all the information available about the errors in a "tidy" data.frame (including information such as the name of the predicate used, the offending value, etc...) and halts execution."